# My Particle filter is not providing approx parameters of the model

Tags: filter, parameters, particles, estimation, linearmodels

Hellow all,

## Particle Filter

I am trying to estimate parameters of a model using particle filter.
I am using simple particle filter to estimate parameters of model. But estimate parameters are not approx near to true parameters and iterations are not converging.

*Can anyone help me optimize the particle filter code to get better estimate parameters and converge the iteration?*

I have provided code of particle filter for your reference.

```
# Universal Failure Rate Function
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y = 0         # Base
K = 10       # Scale
beta = 4    # Shape
alpha = 14    # Scale
num = 500
measurement_noise_std = .3

time = np.linspace(0, 10, num)
UFRF = Y + K*(beta/alpha**beta)*time**(beta-1)

#Add noise to the true data
MFRF = UFRF + np.random.normal(0, measurement_noise_std, size=num)
#MFRF = UFRF + 0.7 * np.random.normal(size=len(UFRF))
plt.plot(time, MFRF)
plt.plot(time, UFRF)

np.random.seed(42) 
beta_space = (2, 8)
alpha_space = (8, 15)
Y_base_space = (-2, 2)
K_scale_space = (5, 15)
num_particles = 1000
motion_model_std = 0.7
std_dev = 0.4
```

## Step 1: Initialization

```
def initialize_particles(num_particles, Y_base_space, K_scale_space, beta_space, alpha_space):
   Y_bases = np.random.uniform(Y_base_space[0], Y_base_space[1], size=num_particles)
   K_scales = np.random.uniform(K_scale_space[0], K_scale_space[1], size=num_particles)
   betas = np.random.uniform(beta_space[0], beta_space[1], size=num_particles)
   alphas = np.random.uniform(alpha_space[0], alpha_space[1], size=num_particles)
   weights = np.ones(num_particles) / num_particles
   return Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights
```

## Step 2: Prediction

```
def predict_particles(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, motion_model_std):
   Y_bases = Y_bases + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(Y_bases))
   K_scales = K_scales + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(K_scales))
   betas = betas + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(betas))
   alphas = alphas + np.random.normal(0, motion_model_std, len(alphas))
return Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas
```

## Step 3: Update

```
def update_weight(observed_data, predicted_data, motion_model_std):
   residual = observed_data - predicted_data
   likelihood = np.exp(-0.5 * np.sum(residual**2) / motion_model_std**2)
   #print(likelihood)
   # Handle potential division by zero
   if np.isclose(likelihood, 0):
      return 1e-100  # Small epsilon value
   else:
return likelihood   

def neff(weights):
return 1. / np.sum(np.square(weights))
```

## Step 4: Resampling

```
def resample(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights):
   indices = np.random.choice(len(Y_bases), size=len(Y_bases), p=weights)
   Y_bases = Y_bases[indices]
   K_scales = K_scales[indices]   
   betas = betas[indices]
   alphas = alphas[indices] 
   N = len(indices)
   if neff(weights) < N:
      #print("true")
      weights = np.ones(len(weights)) / len(weights)  # Reset weights
   else:
     #print("false")
     weights = weights
return Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights    # Reset weights
```

## Main Particle Filter Algorithm for Universal Universal Failure Rate Function Parameter Estimation

```
def particle_filter_MFRF_parameter_estimation(num_particles, Y_base_space, K_scale_space, beta_space, alpha_space, motion_model_std, MFRF, time):

  MFRF = pd.DataFrame(MFRF)  # dataframe
  time = pd.DataFrame(time)  # dataframe

  # Initialization
  Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights = initialize_particles(num_particles, Y_base_space, K_scale_space, 
                                                                  beta_space, alpha_space)

  # Estimate
  Y_base_estimate = np.sum(Y_bases * weights)
  K_scale_estimate = np.sum(K_scales * weights)
  beta_estimate = np.sum(betas * weights)
  alpha_estimate = np.sum(alphas * weights)

  predicted_curve = Y_base_estimate + K_scale_estimate * (beta_estimate/alpha_estimate**
                                                            beta_estimate)*time**(beta_estimate-1)
  residual = MFRF - predicted_curve
  std = pd.Series(np.std(residual))
  std = std.values[0]
  print(std)
  while std >= std_dev:
    
      # Prediction
      Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas = predict_particles(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, motion_model_std)
       
      # Update
      for i in range(num_particles):
        
          # Y + K*(beta/eta**beta)*time**(beta-1)
          predicted_MFRF = Y_bases[i] + K_scales[i] * (betas[i]/alphas[i]**betas[i])*time**(betas[i]-1)
          weights[i] = update_weight(MFRF, predicted_MFRF, motion_model_std)
        
      weights /= np.sum(weights)

      # Resampling
      Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights = resample(Y_bases, K_scales, betas, alphas, weights)
    
    Y_base_estimate = np.sum(Y_bases * weights)
    K_scale_estimate = np.sum(K_scales * weights)
    beta_estimate = np.sum(betas * weights)
    alpha_estimate = np.sum(alphas * weights)

    predicted_curve = Y_base_estimate + K_scale_estimate * (beta_estimate/alpha_estimate**
                                                            beta_estimate)*time**(beta_estimate-1)
    residual = MFRF - predicted_curve
    std = pd.Series(np.std(residual))
    std = std.values[0]
    print(std)
 
# Estimate the parameters as the weighted mean of particles
plt.plot(Y_bases)
plt.plot(K_scales)
plt.plot(betas)
plt.plot(alphas)

return Y_base_estimate, K_scale_estimate, beta_estimate, alpha_estimate
```

## Main Function Execution

```
Y_base_estimate, K_scale_estimate, beta_estimate, alpha_estimate = particle_filter_MFRF_parameter_estimation(
num_particles, Y_base_space, K_scale_space, beta_space, alpha_space, motion_model_std, MFRF, time)
```

## Plot

```
predicted_MFRF = Y_base_estimate + K_scale_estimate * (beta_estimate/alpha_estimate**beta_estimate)*time**(beta_estimate-1)

print("Y_base_estimate = ",Y_base_estimate)
print("K_scale_estimate = ", K_scale_estimate)
print("beta_estimate = ", beta_estimate)
print("alpha_estimate = ", alpha_estimate)
plt.plot(time, predicted_MFRF)
plt.plot(time, MFRF)
```

Comment: This question is likely too broad to be answered here. What is going wrong with the code?